Software to make music
I want to know if there is a software for making music like a music studio app. In previous editions is used to have one, that i never get to work because was too complicated for me where i had to install another app so it works. I have installed now another app on my ubuntu 23.10 its called fl studio, but we have to pay to use it in full.
My question is, is there another app that i can make music?
maybe it is in app center but i dont know the name, i try to find but i cant
my goal is to make music, new songs if i can or at least try

FL Studio is a windows app packaged as snap https://snapcraft.io/flstudio. It is not FOSS. It is not in the official repositories.

How do you want to generate music with an app? Are you looking for a digital keyboard/guitar app? You may find webapps for those.

Free software means the source code is free, not necessarily free to use.

@mikewhatever OP is referring to FL Studio, which is a proprietary windows software available on the snap store. The software available on the official repositories don't have a pay-to-avail-additional-features option.

If there were professional music production software for Linux, I'd have left Windows in 2004.

I don't think asking for a generic list of apps is acceptable.  we used to do that but nowadays those get closed.  https://alternativeto.net/ has all the answers you need regarding music apps for linux

Did you take a look at LMMS? It's available in official repositories or as an appimage.

Does this answer your question? What is the best free OR proprietary DAW running on Ubuntu?

Reaper is a DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) that supports both Windows, MacOS and Linux. Reaper is NOT Open Source.
Reaper is also NOT FREE, but comes at a very reasonable price - $60 for a personal license.
Reaper has many interesting features, such as support for common plugins (VST and AU), as well as its own ReaScript and JSFX plugin formats.
Additionally, Reaper is fully themeable and has its own package manager for installing addons.
Unfortunately, installation on Ubuntu is not very easy, since you have to compile Reaper before installing. There is a guide here, and Reaper also have forums where you can get help with this.

Ubuntu Studio uses Ardour, which is a DAW for Linux. Ardour is Open Source.
Ardour is NOT FREE, since the free version is only a demo. However, you can decide for yourself how much you want to pay for it. If you pay more than $45, you get the next major version as well.
I'm not familiar with Ardour myself, but it looks pretty solid, and has support for AU, LV2, VST and LADSPA plugin formats.
You can download Ardour as a .run file, which can then be installed (the version depends on your payment upon download). The latest Intel/AMD version as of May 2024 is Ardour-8.6.0-x86_64.run.
To install, simply download the file, make it executable and run it.
$ chmod +x ./Ardour-8.6.0-x86_64.run
$ ./Ardour-8.6.0-x86_64.run


Rosegarden is a music composition environment that allows you to edit and create music. It is built around a MIDI sequencer and has basic support for digital audio.
   sudo apt install rosegarden

Audacity can record audio using a microphone or mixer or digitize recordings from another media. You can import, edit, and combine sound file. You can export your recordings in multiple file formats, including multiple files at a time.
   sudo apt install audacity

